# How to extract specific nested elements from a JSON structure in R?

Tags: r, json, r-package

I'm working with a JSON file in R that contains population data for different provinces.

```
{"data":[{"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"}, {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"}, {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"}, {"Manitoba":"MB","MB":"1.28"}, {"Saskatchewan":"SK","SK":"1.1"}]}
```

Each province has an entry with its name, its abbreviation, and then its population associated with the abbreviation. I want to efficiently extract each province's name and its corresponding population into a data frame. How can I do this in R without manually parsing each entry?
I expected json_data to give me a list or data frame but instead, I got a structure with many NAs and couldn't directly correlate provinces to their populations.